# Backup MySQL schema with foreign key table constraints

Tags: sql, schema, backup, mysql

I created my MySQL schema that consists of multiple tables and I decided that I would add the foreign key constraints afterwards for each table, using the command:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

How can I get a backup of the schema (containing the foreign keys) so that I can duplicate it in another machine?

Note that `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and mysqldump do not work in my case because they only create a UNIQUE KEY constraint and not a FOREIGN KEY.

Comment: mysqldump create the dump of foreign keys as well...

Comment: If `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `mysqldump` don't show a table definition with the foreign key constraints that you think you added, the most likely explanation is that you did not add them.  If the constraints were there, they would be visible.

Comment: This is what `SHOW CREATE TABLE experience` returns:

`CREATE TABLE 'experience' (
 'ExperienceID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'OrganizationID' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'UserID' int(11) NOT NULL,
 'PeriodStart' date NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY ('ExperienceID')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=147023 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin`
The UserID is a foreign key and when I check the designer in phpMyAdmin, the foreign keys are graphically shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mysqldump create the dump of foreign keys as well...
it adds syntax like:

```
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
mysql> SOURCE dump_file_name;
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

You can read the manual at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html    for mysqldump of foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

I come across this often. This is how I do it so I can use `'pv'` from the command line to get a progress bar on the `sql` dump while it restores:

```
{ echo "SET foreign_key_checks=0;";pv sql.gz; echo "SET foreign_key_checks=1;"; } | mysql dbname
```

(I put the several commands in `{  }`   so that its treated like a single command when being piped to `mysql` while retaining the progress bar from `'pv'`)

Comment: Very god answer, it automate all steps to load the data so I never forget to set foreing_key_checks again. And pv is a plus.