# MariaDB logical backup restores partially

Tags: mysql

I am new to mariadb.
I am using mysqldump to backup the database. Backup works perfectly but when I tried to restore the backup it's giving errors.

What I observed is while backing up it's sequentially backups the tabels.

While restoring if a table has foreign key dependency and it comes first in the order, backup terminates there itself.

How can backup and restore without failing.

**UPDATE**

I found the answer here

[Backup MySQL schema with foreign key table constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861645/backup-mysql-schema-with-foreign-key-table-constraints)